# Old PHP Version keeps reoccuring in Cellar

Tags: homebrew

I had php55 installed via homebrew and later installed php56 via homebrew. 
I THOUGHT I had uninstalled php55 before installing php56, but am not sure anymore.
Anyhow, the php55 keg keeps magically reappearing in my Cellar folder everytime I restart my Mac, no matter if I uninstalled it before via homebrew or deleted it manually.

I just can't get rid of it, it is annoying! Please someone help me. Is there a list somewhere that tells homebrew which kegs to put in the Cellar on restart?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself:
I forgot that I had added "homebrew.mxcl.php55.plist" to my ~/Library/LaunchAgents.
Remove that, and the keg stops reappearing.

Duh.